# Проблема с ботом для telegram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Всем привет, столкнулся со следующей проблемой:

Код:

```
C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\telegram\vendor\ptb_urllib3\urllib3\connectionpool.py:865: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
```

Почти 4 часа ковыряюсь, ничего так и не получилось :(
Знатоки, помогите

Код:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters

REQUEST_KWARGS={
    'proxy_url': 'socks4://171.103.9.22:4145/',
    'urllib3_proxy_kwargs': {
        'assert_hostname': 'False',
        'cert_reqs': 'CERT_NONE'
    }
}

updater = Updater(token='', use_context=True, request_kwargs=REQUEST_KWARGS)
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

def startCommand(bot, update):
    bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text='Как жизнь?')
def textMessage(bot, update):
    response = 'Получено сообщение -> ' + update.message.text
    bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text=response)

start_command_handler = CommandHandler('start', startCommand)
text_message_handler = MessageHandler(Filters.text, textMessage)

dispatcher.add_handler(start_command_handler)
dispatcher.add_handler(text_message_handler)

updater.start_polling(clean=True)

updater.idle()
```

P.S.:
(Это не помогает)

Код:

```
import requests
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)
```

Код:

```
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
```

Запускаю на win7, vpn не помог :(

Comment: Что ты хочешь сделать ?

Comment: Для начала запустить его.

Answer (score 0):

Так это же warning, уведомляет о том, что соединение не безопасно. Бот при этом должен работать.
А вот `updater.idle()` останавливает инстанс `Updater`, поэтому и не работает.

Именно для `telegram.ext` убирается так:

```
import warnings
from telegram.vendor.ptb_urllib3.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning

warnings.simplefilter('ignore', InsecureRequestWarning)
```